# Why should I use an attached property instead of a regular dependency property?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I just discovered than I can do the following:

```
var button = new Button();
button.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "text");
var text = (string)button.GetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty); // text is "text"
```

While the above example is a bit unrealistic, it does show that I can attach a regular dependency property onto another object. It doesn't have to be a an attached property (`TextBlock.TextProperty` is not registerd with `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached()`.

This bares the questions why are there attached properties in the first place? The only difference I can see for now ist that I can't attach regular dependency properties in XAML. But that's about it. Are there any other differences?

***Update:***

To make it more clear, the below code works and looks pretty close to an attached property from the end users perspective:

```
public static class AttachedPropertyDeclarer
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Button), 
        new PropertyMetadata(default(string),OnTextChanged));

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something when text changed
    }
}

...
button.SetValue(AttachedPropertyDeclarer.TextProperty, "text");
var text = (string)button.GetValue(AttachedPropertyDeclarer.TextProperty);
```

Compare this to the attached property way:

```
public static class AttachedPropertyDeclarer
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(AttachedPropertyDeclarer),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(string),OnTextChanged));

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something when text changed
    }
}
```

The only effective differnce to an attached property here is that I have to declare the owner of type `Button` whereas in a attached property it would usually be `AttachedPropertyDeclarer`. But this only needs to be done if I need a changed event handler (i.e. `OnTextChanged`).

Comment: code in example works because the framework does not restrict SetValue & GetValue based on property registration type ie. attached or regular. secondly a dependency object is a simple container for properties where the DP is key and value is what you store. lastly designer wont allow such usage because the stored will not be of any use as the targeted dependency object does not have knowledge/implementation to use the stored value.

Comment: Why the downvote? How can I improve the question?

Comment: As statated by @pushpraj. They are ment to extend functionality of existing framework controls, for instance. You use DP when you create custom controls of your own, while attached DP are used to extend functionality. Personally I preffer using behaviours in stead, that is when possible. Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff725476(v=expression.40).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Regarding your example, you have *not* as you say, *attached a regular dependency property onto another object*. All your code has achieved is to store a `string` value in a `Dictionary` along with a reference to your object. That does *not* make it an Attached Property - importantly, you cannot access that `string` value from the `Button` directly, as there is no `Text` property on a `Button`.

What your code does is actually very similar to this:

```
Dictionary<object, object> values2 = new Dictionary<object, object>();
var button = new Button();
values2.Add(button, "text");
string text = values2[button].ToString();
```

Now to answer your question:

> The main reason to declare an Attached Property is in order to add a property to a type that you didn't declare, thereby extending its functionality.

A great example of this would be to add a `SelectedItems` property to the `ItemsControl` or `ListBox` class. In doing so, we extend the current, or default functionality of the class. Another good example would be declaring an Attached Property that automatically brings added items into view (again in an `ItemsControl` or `ListBox` class).

UPDATE >>>

According to your comments, you *seem* to be refusing to accept the differences that I have outlined... you said:

> There is literally no difference from the end users perspective except that I can't use it in XAML.

Firstly, do you not think that this is a *huge* difference?.. you won't be able to use it for data binding for a start. Furthermore, you keep saying that you can attach a property to a type that you haven't declared using a `DependencyProperty`, but you are 100% incorrect. You can reference an Attached Property directly in both code *and* XAML, while you can't reference what you are calling your attached property directly in either XAML *or* code.

All you are doing is storing a value in a `Dictionary` and you certainly don't need the overhead of a `DependencyProperty` to do that. There really is no comparison between doing that and declaring an Attached Property. From the [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx#attached_properties_usage) page on MSDN:

> You might create an attached property when there is a reason to have a property setting mechanism available for classes other than the defining class.

Note the following part: *a property setting mechanism*

Adding values into a `Dictionary` is *not* a property setting mechanism. So again, you lose the ability to use your pretend Attached Property in `Style`s, `Animation`s, `Trigger`s, etc.

To clarify this situation for once and for all, you can develop a simple test project. Implement the `IList SelectedItems` Attached Property for a `ListBox` that I mentioned (you can find online tutorials for this) and then do the same using your pretend Attached Property (if it is even possible). The difference in the simplicity of development bewteen the two will clearly show you *why you should use an Attached Property instead of a regular `DependencyProperty`*.

Comment: I suppose the same thing happens when I use an attached property, in that case it would also "store a `string` value in a `Dictionary` along with a reference to my object". I can still "add a property to a type that you didn't declare" using a regular dependency property. It seems to me that the only *real* difference is that I cannot use it in XAML.

Comment: *I can still "add a property to a type that you didn't declare" using a regular dependency property*... that's the point... you *can't* do that with a regular `DependencyProperty`. *It seems to me that the only real difference is that I cannot use it in XAML*... also not true. You cannot use your `Button.Text` property in code either. You can just retrieve the value from the `Dictionary`, which is *not* the same thing *at all*.

Comment: In the code above I did not declare the Type `Button` and I did not declare the DependencyProperty `TextBlock.Text` but I still added a value of the dependency property `TextBlock.Text` to the `Button` instance.

Comment: You set a value into a `Dictionary`, but that doesn't mean that you created or attached anything. Sure, you can store a value like that, but you can't access it using `Button.Text` in any way, so there is no benefit to doing that then just using the free `Tag` property... in fact, using the `Tag` property is an infinitely better option *because you can access that directly in either code or XAML*.

Comment: I have updated my answer to be more clear. There is literally no difference from the end users perspective except that I can't use it in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at dependency property identifier, all ***DP's are registered with class DependencyProperty*** and we pass the Owner class type and property name at time of registration.

Sample:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpinningProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsSpinning", typeof(Boolean), typeof(OwnerClass));
```

At time of registration it creates some unique hash code combining property name and owner class type to represent each DP uniquely.

---

So, when you set value for that DP on some object like in your case on Button, code flow is like this:

First it will get the unique value generated at time of registration of property and add the key value pair in private dictionary named **`_effectiveValues`** declared in class Dependency Object with Key set to unique hashcode at time of registration and value being the value set by user.

**Note - No written documentation for this on MSDN but verified this by peeking into source code using reflector.**

So, when you set the value from code behind it will work like I mentioned above because it does not validate before adding value in the dictionary if it belongs to that type or not and fetching value will get you the value from dictionary.

Not sure but might be constraint is there in XAML only where WPF guys enforced the type check. Sadly there is no written documentation for this on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Attached properties are discovered, when you want to have control over an existing control, but dont want to extend it. A pretty good example is, there is no way to bind BlackOutDates property in XAML for WPF DatePicker. In that case you can use an Attached Property to attach a custom functionality to map the BlackOutDates. This suits good in MVVM, since attached properties provided way for binding in XAML.

```
public class BlackOutDatesAdapter
{
    public static List<DateTime> GetBlackOutDates(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (List<DateTime>)obj.GetValue(BlackOutDatesProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBlackOutDates(DependencyObject obj, List<DateTime> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BlackOutDatesProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BlackOutDates.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BlackOutDatesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BlackOutDates", typeof(List<DateTime>), typeof(BlackOutDatesAdapter), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnBlackOutDatesChanged));

    private static void OnBlackOutDatesChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = sender as DatePicker;
        var list = (List<DateTime>)e.NewValue;
        foreach(var date in list)
        {
            control.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(date));
        }
    }
}
```

Binding in XAML will look like this,

```
<DatePicker VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Width="200"
        local:BlackOutDatesAdapter.BlackOutDates="{Binding BlackOutDates}"
        DisplayDate="{Binding DisplayDate}" />
```

In the callback of property, you can do your own mapping of adding the dates to DatePicker. For more information, please read this [post](http://wpfplayground.com/2014/07/28/wpf-datepicker-blackoutdates-data-binding/).

Comment: I can still do the same thing with a regular dependency property, just not in XAML. So the difference is only the XAML support?

Comment: Yes You can do everything in code-behind. In above example, if violating MVVM is not a problem, then we dont need an attached property. But in MVVM, you cannot write everything in code. Still this is not an ultimate purpose of attached property. In very general, we can tell it helps you to control an object behavior based on another object. Like Grid.Row, where the children of grid need to align based on this property inside Grid. You cannot do this with Dependency Property.